# Initializing const vector with index-dependent function on other vector

Tags: c++, vector, c++14

in C++14, is it possible somehow to initialize a `const` vector using another vector of the same type, while possibly also doing element-dependent operations?

That is, I would like something like this:

```
const vector<double> vec1 = {1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};
vector<double> vec2(4);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    vec2[i] = vec1[i] * 3 + i;
}
```

or some other `i`-dependent operation, but vec2 should be `const` as well.

Comment: You can always cook up your own "transformation range" class that exposes a pair of iterators and a templated conversion function, so the general answer is "yes". Whether that's convenient is for you to decide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course:

```
std::vector<double> foo(const std::vector<double>& v) { ... }

const std::vector<double> vec2 = foo(vec1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because I find writing generic code amusing:

```
template<class F, class C>
C indexed_transform( C in, F&& f ) {
  for (size_t i = 0; i < in.size(); ++i) {
    in[i] = f(i, in[i]);
  }
  return in;
}

const vector<double> vec1 = {1.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};

const std::vector<double> vec2 = indexed_transform(vec1,
  [](size_t i, double d){
    return d*3+i;
  }
);
```

also works with `std::string`, `std::array` (somewhat inefficiently), `std::deque`, and any random-access container.  On random-access ranges, it modifies its incoming argument (and returns it).